# Spring Data Exception Handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I´m working on a project using Spring Data-JPA. I need to handle some exceptions in JpaRepository method calls.

In the code bellow, I need to intercept primary key violations erros but I cannot catch the exception directly. In my case, when an exception of this kind occurs, the UnexpectedRollbackException exception is thrown by repository layer (JpaRepository). I need to search inside this exception object to determine what is the cause of the problem.

I am wondering if there is a more "elegant" way to achieve this.

```
public Phone insert(Phone phone) throws BusinessException {
    Phone result = null;
    try{
        result = phoneRepository.save(phone);
    }
    catch(UnexpectedRollbackException ex){
        if((ex.getCause() != null && ex.getCause() instanceof RollbackException) &&
           (ex.getCause().getCause() != null && ex.getCause().getCause() instanceof PersistenceException) && 
           (ex.getCause().getCause().getCause() != null && ex.getCause().getCause().getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException)){
                throw new BusinessException("constraint violation", ex);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        throw new OuvidorNegocioException("unknown error", ex);
    }       
    return result;
}
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

The code bellow seems to be much better.

```
public Phone insert(Phone phone) throws BusinessException {
    Phone result = null;
    try{
        result = phoneRepository.save(phone);
    }
    catch(UnexpectedRollbackException ex){
        if(ex.getMostSpecificCause() instanceof SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException){
                throw new BusinessException("constraint violation", ex);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        throw new OuvidorNegocioException("unknown error", ex);
    }       
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I disagree with this approach.  Let the Spring data exception be thrown from the data layer and let the service/business layer handle it.  You're sending less information by catching and re-throwning that way.

Comment: Hummm... I really don´t think so. This code is already in my business/service layer. My client layer (html/javascript) only needs to know that a "primary key constraint" was violated. Why to send all the exception structure back if it is not necessary?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wherever you handle the exception, you have the option of looking into the `getMostSpecificCause()` or `getRootCause()` methods of `UnexpectedRollbackException`. [Here is information](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/NestedRuntimeException.html#getRootCause%28%29) about those methods.

Comment: Good. getMostSpecificCause() is what I was looking for. It seems to solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 6):

As with others who have commented on your question — I, too, think the solution you have in your post is a bad one. The sole purpose of a repository abstraction is to hide away the persistence mechanism so that clients don't have to know about it. In your case you look for a low-level SQL Exception which has been intentionally abstracted away by Spring as well as JPA.

If you really want to handle a constraint violation, the `DataIntegrityViolationException` is the correct one to catch. The repositories will wrap the store specific (MongoDB, JPA, whatever you use) in Spring `DataAccessException` subtypes to allow the clients to do exactly that: catch an exception per error type, not per persistence mechanism.

Comment: Thanks Gierke. I see your point. I´ve tried this, but in my case, the insert() method in service layer will be always enrolled in a transaction (Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW). So the generated exception will be an UnexpectedRollbackException that is a subtype of TransactionException. DataAccessException is in another class hierarchy. A catch to DataIntegrityViolationException exception will never be handled.

Comment: Interesting… Looking at the transaction management code in Spring, the only possibility, an `UnexpectedRollbackException` can occur *and* carry a cause is the JTA infrastructure throwing it, not the repository. So what's the reason you have to use JTA transactions in the first place?

Comment: I need the operation (insert/update) enrolled in a transaction because it involves modification in other entities. So, in service layer the method is adorned with @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) attribute. When the repository is called its operations are inside a transaction.

Comment: Any chance you add the stack trace of the `UnexpectedRollbackException` to the question? The situation here is highly suspicious. If you really have `insert(…)` annotated with `@Transactional` *and* the transaction really get's started here (check your tx configuration) the repository invocation *cannot* cause the transaction exception (as there's effectively no transaction functionality invoked at this point). So without a stack trace (and more precise documentation of your transaction setup, it's really hard to judge what's going on.

Comment: If the database has multiple constraints on a table, a save could fail on any one of those constraints. If service layer is catching the spring data exception how does it identify which constraint? Also I would not even put this exception handling in service but move into repository layer and throw specific exception. With Spring data respository, how would we mark our repository with those throwable exceptions?