# How to handle Optional from Service to Controller in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Spring JPA returns an Optional. I return the Optional from the Service. There if Optional is not present I pass error to model. The other case if there is a database error for example database not available, I do not catch these exceptions. If that happens user will see this exception in browser. I do not know how to handle this very rare error. For me this should never happen and if it does, ok . I do not want to handle this exception all the time. What do you think about my architecture.

Service:

```
    @Override
    public Optional<Client>  findClientById(Long id) {

         return  clientRepository.findById(id);

   }
```

Controller:

```
Optional<Client> client= clientService.findClientById(id);
if(client.isPresent())
{
    model.addAttribute("client", client.get());
}
else 
{
    model.addAttribute("error", "No clientfound with this ID!!");
}
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't pass error as an attribute in your model - that's REST anti-pattern. The best way to hand this is to use HTTP codes, e.g. return 502. To do so, you may wrap your exceptions up your code into HttpResponse. To catch your exception, you may approach similar to method that [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000110/spring-data-exception-handling), i.e. catch spring data exception, wrap it up a way you wanted and throw on higher level for processing.